# Filtering List objects by object type

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have a List of Objects (ordered) which are already grouped by object type.

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add(new Integer());
myList.add(new Integer());
myList.add("string");
myList.add(new Double());
myList.add(new Double());
myList.add(new Double());
```

How can I elegantly loop through the groups of objects without using *instanceof* operator?

I essentially want this:

```
List<List<Object>> result;
```

I do not know what object types there are, so the simpleton approach would be to loop like this:

```
Object obj = iter.next();
String thisClass = obj.class.getSimpleName();
if (!thisClass.equals(lastClass)){
  currentList = new ArrayList();
}
currentList.add(obj);
```

however perhaps a stream would be nice, something like:

```
myList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Class::getSimpleName, Collectors.<IBaseDO>toList()));
```

yes this results in a compile error as I can't get the syntax just right.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you please post the full code (combined) that's not compiling? I'm not sure how you grouped everything together or even what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ergonaut, having these different types of objects in one list already indicates there's something wrong with your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very bad design.

Yet, you can do:

```
List<List<Object>> grouped = 
    myList.stream()
          .collect(collectingAndThen(
                       groupingBy(Object::getClass, LinkedHashMap::new, toList()), 
                       map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values)
          ));
```

Comment: Can the collector return a list?  The Map isn't ordered.

Comment: What order do you need?

Comment: The same order as in my original list.